# there is error while creating derby database SQLSTATE; XBM0H

Tags: java, database, jdbc, derby

I am getting this error while creating database in java derby

```
Fri Dec 02 18:24:53 PKT 2016 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Fri Dec 02 18:24:54 PKT 2016 : access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "localhost:1527" "listen,resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkListen(SecurityManager.java:1134)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(ServerSocketFactory.java:231)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.createServerSocket(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: do you want to create the database with java program?

Comment: yes I want to create database with java but these are the error I get when I give database name user and password to database and click on 'ok'

Comment: The Java security manager is denying Derby from opening the network socket on port 1527. Read this manual to learn about that: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/security/csecjavasecurity.html